# Package installation paths not writeable

Tags: r, permissions, bioconductor

I freshly installed both R and Rstudio (latest version) on Ubuntu v22.04. I installed the latest version of BiocManager with the command:

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.17")
```

However, when I tried to install DESeq2 (or other packages like AnnotationDbi) with

```
BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
```

I keep having the same error:

```
The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp6OyxTE/downloaded_packages’
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: /usr/lib/R/library
  packages:
boot, foreign
  path: /usr/lib/R/site-library
  packages:
bit, broom, bslib, curl, digest, gargle, googledrive, googlesheets4, highr, isoband, jsonlite, ragg
```

I checked and the two paths belong to the root. However, I also searched online and is completely normal because these two library are installed alongside with R.

I checked with the command

> .libPaths()
> [1] "/home/my_name/R/my_computer_name/4.3" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
> [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                        "/usr/lib/R/library"

Therefore, I have a separate library (where BiocManager had been installed) and where I can install other packages.

How can I solve this issue? I can't install any packages in this way...

Comment: Do you know how those packages might have been installed to "/usr/lib/R/site-library"? Are you on a shared system? It seems like someone must have installed those with administrator privileges. This causes a problem because now you can't update them without the same administrator privileges. Do you have admin privileges so you can remove those packages that shouldn't be there?

Comment: I installed R following the official tutorial "https://cloud.r-project.org" and Rstudio from the Posit official installer. 
Removing these packages is not the best idea as I read then R will not work properly anymore

Comment: I'm not sure which official tutorial you are trying to link to. Most of the package you have listed are not required R packages. They should have been installed in a user library, not the system library. It's not clear where exactly you are running your code or how you got to this unusual configuration state.

Comment: I followed the Cran official page for Ubuntu installation. I tried to uninstall R and install everything again. I had the same problem with the system library but with different packages. However, I found a way to update these packages from the command line with "sudo R" and ".libPaths" so now I am finally able to use rstudio and install other packages in my user library